# Managing UITableView contentInsets

Tags: ios, uitableview, insets

I have controller, call it **ActionBarViewController** (it inherits **UIViewController**). It has view, call it **ActionBarView**. That view has 2 subviews - **contentView** and **actionBar**. **contentView** frame equals to **ActionBarView** frame. **actionBar** frame is small frame at bottom part of **ActionBarView** frame.

I have one more controller - **ListViewController** (it inherits UITableViewController). I use it as childViewController with **ActionBarViewController** as parent. **ListViewController**'s view (tableView) set as **contentView** of **ActionBarView**.

As result, i have UITableViewController that is childViewController. ParentViewController view has additional subview - action bar.

For correct table view scrolling i add/remove additional contentInsets of tableView on actionBar show/hide. But ListViewController add/remove contentInsets on his own when keyboard appeared/disappeared.

Finally, when keyboard shown tableView has complex bottom insets, keyboard insets and actionBar insets.

[image]
[image]

Questions:
Any body knows correct way to resolve this issue?
In which point UITableViewController change tableView insets? How to override it?

P.S.: All views and controllers creating programmatically.